# How to calculate full (mechanical) energy on the hyperbolic orbit?

Tags: orbit

For example, for a comet that travels on the hyperbolic orbit around the sun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total energy is the sum of the [kinetic energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) and the [potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy). It is constant, unless some interaction such as a collision between bodies occurs.

The kinetic energy is easy to understand. For a mass $m$ and velocity $v$ it is given by

$$E_k = ½mv^2$$

The potential energy formula is (technically) given as

$$U = -μm/r$$

where $μ$ is the [Standard gravitational parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter). (I say technically because it can be hard to grasp the concept of negative energy. See the linked articles).

In the case of a hyperbolic orbit the velocity and distance from the sun must be measured; one cannot be derived from the other as is the case with a known elliptical orbit.

See also

- [Specific orbital energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy)
- [Gravitational energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy)
- [Gravitational constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant)

Comment: Is it allowed to ask another related question here ?

Comment: We prefer that you post a new question, especially after there is already an answer :-)